# Cache Sink with Derived Column Transformation in Data Flow to replace code by libellé

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I started my apprenticeship on Azure and on Synapse in particular and I need your help please:
Where can I find interesting training on Synapse?

Secondly, I have a little blockage in this situation, Can anyone offer me some help ans leads:

I want to add libellé from table A to table B and I don't know what function or transformation can allow me to do this

I tested the derived column transformation using: Each column that matches:libCached#lookup(name).Column_Name

the transformation formula: libCached#lookup(toString($$)).Option_LBL

Thank you very much for your help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY761.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hblog.jpg)

Normally I try to replace the values of the columns of (table B) referenced in (column_name Table A) by label (Option_LBL)
example of your expected output: in array B

replace 1 with Active and 0 with Resolved and 99 with Canceled

Comment: Hi, can you please provide the sample of your expected output and the snip of your derived column?

Comment: Normally I try to replace the values of the columns of (table B) referenced in (column_name Table A) by label (Option_LBL)
example of your expected output: in array B

replace 1 with Active and 0 with Resolved and 99 with Canceled

Answer (score 0):

You can use [case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#case) expression in `derived column` transformation to replace column values.

`case(Status=='Active', 1, Status=='Resolved',0,Status=='Cancelled',99)`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I am trying to create a generic formula that processes all the fields of the table,

what I'm trying to do is tell it to find me in my base table (B), the columns that match with the cache sink and replace their values by THE LABELS (Option_LBL) in table A

suddenly in direved column I managed to do the first condition which is to find the columns that match but I block on the second part to replace by the labels